# The most similar java GUI framework to android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, frameworks

I am android developer and love android GUI system. What's the closest to this I can get for java desktop applications?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637529/java-desktop-development-framework-similar-to-android).